# Where can I find Chrome Custom Tabs .jar library?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

**Hello,** everyone! I would like to ask, where could I find Chrome Custom Tabs .jar library?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find jar file directly to help you, but you can create jar file from dependencies by following [this](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)

Hope it helps!!!